# PHP odbc_connect Login failed for user

Tags: php, sql, odbc

Im trying to connect to SQL Server via ODBC with PHP. I created System DNS connection with ODBC Data Source Administrator and is fine, i test the Data Source and the connection is successful, but when i use the same Data Source from PHP with odbc_connect the login is failing: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for use.....

It used to be ok and working but recently the password was changed, and now i cannot make it work. The password contains chars like (* ( and | )

Can the problem with PHP odbc_connect comes from those special chars used for the SQL user password?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Everything's possible but, since `odbc_connect()` has a separate parameter for the password (vs. forcing you to inject the password into a DSN string or something) I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: Found the problem i just forgot to mention that the pass was containing \ char. That was the issue. When i removed \ char from the pass everything went fine

Comment: PHP strings *can* hold backslashes but you need to escape them properly.